# How to make use of GWT Serialization in RequestBuilder and Servlets

Tags: gwt, servlets

I'm using GWT RPC Calls for Server Side Request so far and it's pretty good. I'm planning on separating my Code into Servlets and GWT Client Side. Since i'm using RPC calls, it seems impossible. The Reason i want to do like this is , i'm planning to provide white labeling option for my App. So if i could separate the  code to client code and servlets, i can simply provide the White Labeled client code to my Partners to host on their server. I have checked with GWT RequestBuilder and `Access-Control Allow-Origin : Origin from Client Header` and it works fine.

However i need to implement gwt-serialization over RequestBuilder request and Servlet Responses. How can i do this ..?

Scenario I like to make:

1. RequestBuilder sending Serializable String(Which is a `IsSerialiazible` object) to Servlet.
2. Servlet deserializes the String to Java Object,Processes and Returns the String Response of a 'IsSerialiazable' Object.
3. The Response String recieved in GWT RequestBuilder deserialzes it back to a Java Object(JS after Compiling).

I have checked on RemoteServiceServlet class which seems to have some info on serializing and deserializing request and response. But i couldn't get it right to get it to work with RequestBuilder. Any ideas , Hope it will be helpful for everyone.

```
    public final void processPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) 
    throws IOException, ServletException,SerializationException 
    {
        // Read the request fully.
        //
        String requestPayload = readContent(request);

        // Let subclasses see the serialized request.
        //
        onBeforeRequestDeserialized(requestPayload);

        // Invoke the core dispatching logic, which returns the serialized
        // result.
        //
        String responsePayload = processCall(requestPayload);

        // Let subclasses see the serialized response.
        //
        onAfterResponseSerialized(responsePayload);

        // Write the response.
        //
        writeResponse(request, response, responsePayload);
    }
```

Comment: You haven't given any Solution, how can i accept? In fact you have given some wrong facts[GWT Request Builder - fire requests for static resources it can be used to fetch Data also]. My question is clear, i just want the algorithm or the java & js source for GWT Serialization. Are you sure you have answered that ..?

Comment: Read the second line of my comment. Post update if you have any so the community can learn from your findings. Also, RPC is not built over RequestBuilder. You do not need to get hostile!!!!

Comment: Buddy i'm not getting hostile, i haven't received any answer me or the community can accept, but you are forcing me to accept your answer. Is that really right ..?  Try this link, this is what i'm getting at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/rR71s0wwQRo

Comment: Try this link too Buddy : http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:jectbd.com/%3Fp%3D1174&strip=1 , i was able to get only cached  page only, the link's not working anymore.

Comment: the jectbd link is not functional the google/forum thread is interesting. Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: You are welcome buddy, i'll share more,once i get what i'm looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to get the GWT Serialization  & Deserialization source.Unfortunately, i have been stuck with other works and couldn't look on this right now. When i get the GWT Serialization Classes , i will update.

Answer (score 1):

GWT RPC and RequestBuilder serve different purposes. We cannot mix/match them.

GWT RPC - Services which fetch Data

GWT Request Builder - fire requests for static resources like js,css, json objects, querying soap services etc

The only feasible solution at the top of my mind for your approach of servicing requests is by using JSON -  https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON

You can keep your servlets code as is and then use RequestBuilder to query URL mapped to these servlets for JSON objects. Process the JSON objects using JSNI or Overlay concepts.

Comment: I know that RPC & RequestBuilder are different, but RPC internally uses RequestBuilder, so it must send the post data as GWt Serialized data from RequestBuilder. So i just want to make use of both these functionalities(ReqBuilder& GWT Serialization) of GWT. I'm trying to navigate through the source of GWT,thats why i'm taking time and got stuck with some other works too. That's why i'm taking time to reply. I will reply you shortly

Comment: I'm already using JSON with GWT RequestBuilder even for CORS, but i wanted to use GWT Serialization, such as my Post Parameters serialized to string(plain-text) for HTTP and the deserialization.